# how to sum nominal by _id method ? nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array

```js
let data = [{
    _id: '6081710355cebfa52c91f006',
    number: '081218302334',
    method: {
      deposite: 0,
      withdraw: 0,
      _id: '6081702cef267a9d14f08097',
      name: 'mandiri',
      __v: 0
    },
    nominal: 150000,
    member: '607ecffc03e9bd6a4dc24861',
    admin: 'dhimas hertianto',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '6081711555cebfa52c91f007',
    number: '081218302334',
    method: {
      deposite: 0,
      withdraw: 0,
      _id: '60817032ef267a9d14f08098',
      name: 'bca',
      __v: 0
    },
    nominal: 17000,
    member: '607ecffc03e9bd6a4dc24861',
    admin: 'dhimas hertianto',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: '6081711555cebfa52c91f007',
    number: '081218302334',
    method: {
      deposite: 0,
      withdraw: 0,
      _id: '60817032ef267a9d14f08098',
      name: 'bca',
      __v: 0
    },
    nominal: 17000,
    member: '607ecffc03e9bd6a4dc24861',
    admin: 'dhimas hertianto',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

and expected :

```
[
  {
    id : ,
    name : mandiri,
    nominal : 15000
  },
  {
    id : ,
    name : bca,
    nominal : 34000
  },
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+sum+object+array+id+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: `id : ,` is not valid object entry

Answer (score 0):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/diw-TzIQP4P

Use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: { _id: "$method.name", nominal: { $sum: "$nominal" } }
  },
  {
    $project: { _id: 0, name: "$_id", nominal: 1 }
  }
])
```

---

```
[
  {
    "name": "bca",
    "nominal": 34000
  },
  {
    "name": "mandiri",
    "nominal": 150000
  }
]
```